# Add settings button to app info screen

Tags: android

Since Android N it is possible to add a settings button to the app info screen like in the picture below but I cant find any information about how to implement this?

[image]

I guess we only have to specify an intent filter for an Activity but which one do we have to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this on Android 7.0 and higher, simply by add this line of code to your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked great! I tested this on an Oreo emulator and the icon does not show up (potential bug) but you can click where it should appear and it starts the activity.

Comment: Your welcome, yeah seems like a bug have same problem. Haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Does anyone has any solution how to display the gear icon properly? in Android 8.0 it is not showing the icon however the area is clickable. Seems like the corresponding assets is not available. It will be great if anyone can help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 7.0 and higher, you can use this `<intent-filter>` on your settings activity:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

The Settings app should pick that up and make it available to the user via that gear icon.